# Two keys in a map literal shouldn't be equal. Change or remove the duplicate key

Tags: flutter, dart, ransack

We would like to filter data where the paymentStatus is "Coming Due" and "Overdue" using [Ransack](https://activerecord-hackery.github.io/ransack/getting-started/search-matches/), but only get "Overdue" data.

```
Future<ListResponse?> getData(
      GetParams params) async {
    Map<String, dynamic> commonParams = {
            ....
      "q[payment_status_in][]": "Coming Due",
      "q[payment_status_in][]": "Overdue"
    };

    Response response = await Dio()
        .get('$kBaseUrl/xxx', queryParameters: commonParams);

    var res = ListResponse.fromJson(response.data);

    if (res.status != true) {
      throw ServerException(res.errorMessage![0]);
    }

    return res;
  }
```

Here the warning message:

> Two keys in a map literal shouldn't be equal. Change or remove the
> duplicate key

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are there duplicate keys on the map? The last value will obviously replace the previous one with the same key. If you want to send a list as query parameters, try

```
"q[payment_status_in]": ["Coming Due", "Overdue"]
```

Comment: thanks..I wrote like this, it works `"q[payment_status_in][]": ["Coming Due", "Overdue"]`